# Java Reflection: "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException"

Tags: java, class, reflection, methods

I am trying to get the method from another class using reflection, but for some reason it keeps on giving me a no such method exception. These are the classes im using:

ScriptTable class:

```
for(Class<?> script: Scripts) {
        System.out.println(script.getName());
        try {
            Method c = script.getMethod("scriptInfo()", script);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

DummyScript class

```
    public String[] scriptInfo() {
    String[] ScriptInfo = {"DummyScript", "Chris", "Does nothing atm"};
    return ScriptInfo;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you sampled your code instead of pastebin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
script.getMethod("scriptInfo()", script);
```

change it to:

```
script.getMethod("scriptInfo");
```

and look here to see why:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29